# how to avoid escape letters in reading text file

Tags: bash, csv, backslash

I'm reading a CSV file separated by ';'.
As basic example consider this "file.csv":

```
a1;a2;/unixpath/file1;a4
b1;b2;\winpath\file2;b4
```

Some fields contain windows path, and so use the backslash and are unquoted.

I'm using this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileIn="file.csv"
IFS=';'
while read -a lineV ; do
   #echo "lineV: '${lineV[@]}'"
   for ((c=0; c<=3; c++)); do
      field="${lineV[$c]}"
      echo -E "c:$c field:'$field' '${lineV[$c]}'"
   done
   echo "---"
done < $fileIn
```

The output always skip backslash as so:

```
c:0 field:'a1' 'a1'
c:1 field:'a2' 'a2'
c:2 field:'/unixpath/file1' '/unixpath/file1'
c:3 field:'a4' 'a4'
---
c:0 field:'b1' 'b1'
c:1 field:'b2' 'b2'
c:2 field:'winpathfile2' 'winpathfile2'
c:3 field:'b4' 'b4'
---
```

I tryed adding quotes but same results.
I added -E to echo, same results.

How can I read backslash as literal '\' ?

Comment: If you had given [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) a crack at your script, it would have made a suggestion aimed directly at your issue.  Note that the [[tag:bash]] tag wiki instructs you to use ShellCheck before posting your script here for troubleshooting assistance.

Comment: BTW, `echo` is unreliable with or without `-E`, _particularly_ when handling strings with backslash literals. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the POSIX echo standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, or for a more general overview, the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113). One thing you'll note is that `echo -E` is supposed to print `-E` on output, and any `echo` that _doesn't_ do that is noncompliant.

Comment: OP explicitly use `bash`, so not POSIX.

Comment: (bash's `echo` is _sometimes_ compliant, based on configuration that can be set either at compile-time or at runtime -- and at runtime is influenced by environment variables, _and_ `shopt` operations, _and_ `argv[0]` -- so you can't trust what it'll do when `-E` or `-e` is passed).

Comment: @GillesQuénot, you interrupted me partway through a multi-comment sidebar. Bash's `echo` implementation follows POSIX to unpredictably varying degrees; if bash's runtime flag `xpg_echo` was turned on at compile-time, or through an environment variable, or through a shopt call, you no longer get "default" `echo -E` behavior (and `set -o posix` and `xpg_echo` have further interactions that a comment isn't suitable to address).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-r` switch:

```
while IFS=';' read -r -a lineV ; do
```

for hardening the use of this while loop.

That yields:

```
c:0 field:'a1' 'a1'
c:1 field:'a2' 'a2'
c:2 field:'/unixpath/file1' '/unixpath/file1'
c:3 field:'a4' 'a4'
---
c:0 field:'b1' 'b1'
c:1 field:'b2' 'b2'
c:2 field:'\winpath\file2' '\winpath\file2'
c:3 field:'b4' 'b4'
---
```

---

`help read`:

> -r    do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

---

See [bash FAQ#1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score -2):

found. Using:

`while read -ra lineV ; do`

will avoid interpreting backslash

Comment: What do you add to existing answer? I already use `-r`